# Is there a way to sort the output in the Tortoisehg console window?

Tags: windows, cmd, pipe, tortoisehg

I can run hg commands in the TortoiseHg console window. Sometimes I want to pipe to another command to filter output or sort. Not really sure how to do this in TortoiseHg (although I know I can run hg commands in the 'Cmd' window and pipe to another command like a normal batch file).

I've tried both Unix and Windows CMD versions of piping the output. As a simple example (to illustrate the issue, but not necessarily the limits of what I could try...):

```
Unix:  hg branches | grep -i inactive 
CMD:   hg branches | findstr /I inactive
```

Neither of these will work in the TortoiseHg **"Console"** window. I would find it more convenient to run commands in the console window than in the CMD shell as my typed commands would be shown chronologically with other commands executed via the GUI (that normally show in the Console window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Even if your host OS is Windows, you can have (now) 2 shells in command-prompt (directly or as Terminal Window in THG): classic CMD and PowerShell. Defining which type you use will be better for faster understanding of a problem
2. Same shell as command-prompt or Terminal will produce absolutely the same result

Your cmd-sample "just work", can't see any troubles here (win32chcp is local extension for console outputs, irrelevant to tasks)

**Terminal THG**

```
THG\hg-git>hg branches | findstr /I inactive
[win32chcp] switching your console encoding into cp1251
1.0.x                       2155:ae8b3247c149 (inactive)
0.10.x                      2118:4a18ab4b2fed (inactive)

THG\hg-git>
```

**CMD-window**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1766]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

THG\hg-git>hg branches | findstr /I inactive
[win32chcp] switching your console encoding into cp1251
1.0.x                       2155:ae8b3247c149 (inactive)
0.10.x                      2118:4a18ab4b2fed (inactive)

THG\hg-git>
```

Comment: When I run either of these commands in TortoiseHG 6.1.3 directly as you show, I get error 'hg branches: invalid arguments' as if it doesn't understand the pipe symbol and commands following the pipe. Unlike what your answer above shows, my TortoiseHG console gives me a prompt the looks like `RepoName% hg brances | findstr /I inactive` to which I get an error `hg branches: invalid arguments` and `[command returned code 255 Wed Jul  6 18:52:02 2022]` and it showing the "help" manpage for the `branches` command with the various parameters it accepts.

Comment: Well, there are already at least three "shells" on Windows 10/11 - __PowerShell Console__ `powershell.exe`, __Windows Command Prompt__ `cmd.exe` and with __Windows Subsystem for Linux__ also a `bash` __shell__. They are all supported by the [Windows Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal) being designed as replacement for the [Windows Console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Console) although both exist parallel on Windows 10/11. (Yes, even the pure text user interface is really complicated to manage nowadays.)

Comment: The redirection with `|` is done be the command interpreter (`cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe` or `bash` in WSL). @RussThils It looks like you enter the command in prompt of *TortoiseHG* itself and not in prompt of one of the three command interpreters which is the reason why the redirection does not work and why the error message about invalid arguments is output by *TortoiseHg*. If you want to use redirections, you have to run the `hg` commands from prompt of `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe` or `bash` in a Windows Console or Windows Terminal window and not in *TortoiseHg* console.

Comment: @Mofi - real shell can be called inside THG also as "Terminal" ("Repository" -> "Terminal" or `Ctrl+Shift+T`)

Comment: @Mofi, yes, I think you are correct. I guess I was assuming the "Console" Pane in the THG GUI was either an integrated linux/cmd/power shell and therefore could pipe and redirect output, perhaps even with syntax of `hg <somecommand> | cmd -c "findstr /I <somestring>"` or `hg <somecommand> | bash -c "findstr /I <somestring>"`.  However, it appears the "Console" pane is simply an in-built Mercurial command parser with no ability to even run simple shell commands. Thus, it is not possible to use Console pane to process or capture output (and show the GUI command output in chronological sequence).

Comment: LazyBadger/Mofi Thank you for both of your help. It seems my question wasn't completely clear to either of you, but you both answered enough pieces for me to deduce I was making a wrong assumption and that the "Console" Pane directly in the GUI doesn't offer the capabilities I was hoping for. I can see that if I want to modify output of a command, I must do that in one of the external disconnected shells provided by Windows (Ctrl-Shift-T is just a shortcut to the CMD shell).